# Need to add for loop to add a lot of .csv files in the tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

[image]

I am trying to plot data from .csv file. I have a lot of .csv files (around 4000). I am not sure how to do this. I am looking for some kind of "for loop" to perform this. Any help would be appreciated. I have attached an example code below.

I have data a lot of data files and I do not want to add one line of code for all .csv files. I hope this explains my problem.

```
%\title{Plot_for_gain_tuning_paper}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{4pt}
\pgfplotsset{width=9.75cm,compat=1.3} 
\pgfplotsset{every axis legend/.append style={at={(0.45,-0.25)},legend columns=5,anchor=south,font=\small}}
\tikzset{every mark/.append style={scale=0.8}}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[title=$V_{a_{rms}}+V_{b_{rms}}+V_{c_{rms}}$,xlabel={Time (in seconds)},ylabel={Voltage (in Volts)},grid=major,legend entries={$Index~1$,$Index~2$,$Index~3$,$Index~4$,$Index~5$}]
\addplot[color=black,style=solid,very thick] table [col sep=comma] {Data_128_4_1.csv};
\addplot[color=black,style=solid,very thick] table [col sep=comma] {Data_128_4_2.csv};
\addplot[color=black,style=solid,very thick] table [col sep=comma] {Data_128_4_3.csv};
\addplot[color=black,style=solid,very thick] table [col sep=comma] {Data_128_4_4.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It would be helpful to know the pattern by which the files are named. Is it as straightforward as it looks: `Data_128_4_1.csv`, ..., `Data_128_4_4000.csv`?

Comment: The data looks something like the following: 0,0
0.2,0
0.2,0
0.2,0
0.51962,0
0.81224,0
1.3398,0 
..... etc. The problem I am facing here is not with the csv files, but how I include this in the latex code. I have data files from "Data_128_4_1.csv" to "Data_128_4_1000.csv". I am trying to avoid writing 1000 lines of \addplot. Hope this answers the question.

Comment: I have uploaded a picture which shows the typical data in the .csv file.

Comment: I meant the filenames, not the content.

Comment: The basic principle might be: `\foreach \C in {1,2,...,1000} {\addplot[<options>]{Data_128_4_\C.csv};}`.  Hard to do more on my end without constructing a large number of `.csv` files to test with....

Comment: Yes. "Data_i_j_k.csv" is the format I use to name the csv files. i and j are from 1 to 4, and k varies from 1 to 1000.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a collection of files that has a regular 'progression' of filenames, the `\foreach` command (from the package `pgffor`, a utility package for `tikz`) can be helpful.  Instead of

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[title=$V_{a_{rms}}+V_{b_{rms}}+V_{c_{rms}}$,xlabel={Time (in seconds)},ylabel={Voltage (in Volts)},grid=major,legend entries={$Index~1$,$Index~2$,$Index~3$,$Index~4$,$Index~5$}]
\addplot[color=black,style=solid,very thick] table [col sep=comma] {Data_128_4_1.csv};
\addplot[color=black,style=solid,very thick] table [col sep=comma] {Data_128_4_2.csv};
\addplot[color=black,style=solid,very thick] table [col sep=comma] {Data_128_4_3.csv};
...
\addplot[color=black,style=solid,very thick] table [col sep=comma] {Data_128_4_1000.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

you could have:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
        title=$V_{a_{rms}}+V_{b_{rms}}+V_{c_{rms}}$,
        xlabel={Time (in seconds)},
        ylabel={Voltage (in Volts)},
        grid=major,
        legend entries={$Index~1$,$Index~2$,$Index~3$,$Index~4$,$Index~5$}
    ]

    \foreach \F in {1,2,...,1000}{
            \addplot[
                color=black,
                style=solid,
                very thick
            ] table [col sep=comma] {Data_128_4_\F.csv};
        }

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```